# Can FFmpeg perform audio phase subtraction?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, signal-processing

I can do audio phase subtraction in Adobe Audition like so:

How can I do this with FFmpeg? Is it possible?

I've googled for audio phase subtraction, and looked at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html, nothing seems to work for me.

I want to do phase subtraction in batches and support for stereo audio.

Comment: You can do this in something like Audacity, but why the need for batch processing? It's the kind of thing that only works if you have absolute phase-alignment to start with*. I struggle to see a use case you would have multiple examples of this type of overlay with identical start-points/phase alignment. It makes the whole question feel like a bit of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) *[I didn't watch the whole thing, but did the guy tell you it took him 20 minutes to phase-align his example before he started the video?]

Comment: See the [aeval](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aeval) filter.

Comment: @tetsujin I want to compare audio compression using different codecs, with perfectly aligned audio files. Additionally, I want to compare audio encoding across various scenarios, which is why I need to perform this task in batches.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input0.wav -i input1.wav \
  -filter_complex \
  "[1]    aeval  = -val(0) | -val(1)                     [a]; \
   [0][a] amerge = inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3 [b]" \
  -map "[b]" -c:a flac output.flac
```

This command subtracts `input1.wav` from `input0.wav` and assumes that both inputs are stereo.

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation for manipulating audio channels.